# How to retrieve and deploy translations in salesforce?

Tags: workbench, deployment

I want to deploy some traslations made via workbench , i made the following XML file to retrieve the modifications (the field is a picklist called `Type` under `Event` object), but it does not work, the `objectTranslations` file retrieved is empty knowing that the translations in spain exist in workbench !!! do you have any idea how to make it work ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

  <types>
        <members>Event.Type</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
  </types>
  <types>
      <members>Event-es</members>
      <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
  </types>
  <version>33.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: What translations are you trying to retrieve? The picklist values of the field Type on the Event object right?

Comment: yes that is exactly what a wanna do

Comment: it should be in ObjectTranslations folder, not file

Comment: Yes, the folder is there, but the file is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your issue in a developer org.

It failed indeed using your above package.xml.

I then started fiddling and found that upgrading the API version in your package xml resolves the issue. This is the package xml I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Event.Type</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>    
    <types>
       <members>Event-es</members>
        <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <version>37.0</version>
</Package>
```

Not sure why updating the API version works. I hope this works for you.

Comment: i will try it  and keep you updated

Comment: Yes, it works. thank you saved me a lot of time and efforts